# Can I code a Unity extension to get effect of applying Dependency attribute to all public properties?

Tags: c#, unity-container

I'm thinking it should be easy but I don't know the exact mechanics of doing this (see question title).

The way it would work might be like this:

```
[AutoInjectProperties]
public class C
{
  public class C(bool b)
  {
    if(b)
    {
      this.MyClass3 = new MyClass3(); // prevents auto inject
    }
  }
  public MyClass1 { get; set; } // auto inject
  public MyClass2 { get; }
  public MyClass3 { get; set; } // auto inject if null after construction
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use the `DependencyAttribute` at all. [It is not a recommended practice](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/01/27/WhatsSoDangerousAboutADIAttribute.aspx). Use the `DependencyProperty` instead.

```
container.RegisterType<IMyInterface, MyImplementation>(new DependencyProperty("Foo"));
```

If the dependencies you are injecting are mandatory, you should use constructor injection instead of property injection. Unity figures out constructor parameters on its own.

```cs
public class MyImplementation
{
  private readonly IFoo foo;
  public MyImplementation(IFoo foo)
  {
    if(foo == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("foo");
    this.foo = foo;
  }
  public IFoo Foo { get { return this.foo; } }
}
```

If you register `IFoo` before you resolve `MyImplementation` Unity will do its job and inject it for you.

---

**Update**

```cs
public class AllProperties : InjectionMember
{
  private readonly List<InjectionProperty> properties;
  public AllProperties()
  {
    this.properties = new List<InjectionProperty>();
  }
  public override void AddPolicies(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, string name, IPolicyList policies)
  {
    if(implementationType == null)throw new ArgumentNullException("implementationType");
    // get all properties that have a setter and are not indexers
    var settableProperties = implementationType
      .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
      .Where(pi => pi.CanWrite && pi.GetSetMethod(false) != null && pi.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0);
    // let the Unity infrastructure do the heavy lifting for you
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in settableProperties)
    {
      this.properties.Add(new InjectionProperty(property.Name));
    }
    this.properties.ForEach(p => p.AddPolicies(serviceType, implementationType, name, policies));
  }
}
```

Use it like that

```
container.RegisterType<Foo>(new AllProperties());
```

It will inject all properties that have a public setter.

Comment: sometimes I like to use things in creative ways for convenience though - i think it might be nice to have a switch I could flip and all my public read/write properties would just come out of the container with an instance instead of their defulat null (generally useless)

Comment: the unity infrastructure will then take care of recursive injection of type members?

Comment: @AaronAnodide what do you mean by recursive injection of type members? If MyClass1/2/3 has dependencies they will be resolved as well.

Comment: yep, that's what I meant, thanks for taking the time to help me even though it probably goes against your philosophies to do something like that